# Deleting millions of rows without impacting transaction log

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our client database is growing at increasing pace, more specifically entities like Auditing & Logging which are growing much greater speed.
For instance, as of now the Auditing table has ~30 million rows and its is growing with the rate of 1.5 million rows per week.
Similarly, the Logging table is growing at the rate of ~1 million  rows per week. This table has ~50 million rows.
We have decided to archive tables based on our data retention policy & delete some 'N' number of records from these tables when ever archiving jobs runs.

I am looking for best advice for defining the chuckSize which will not impact transaction logs of sql server db or table locking. I know this value cannot be straight way derived, we need to run different test scenarios to come with this magic number.

Comment: wht % percent of data you want to keep ? you will retain some data and put rest in Archive table then delete those records.Is this your flow ?

Answer (score 1):

The best advice is to partition by data, presumably by date.

Then you can remove entire partitions without having to log the results.

The subject of partitioning tables is rather broad.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) is a good place to start.

Comment: To be explicit, `truncate table` accepts a partition number or range so one your table is set up this way you can trim your data in a way that is minimally logged.